# How to provide /dev/sda to already existing file system?

Tags: 14.04, partitioning, mount

I am new to file system. I have file system file with name rootfs.ext3 and when I mount it to some directory , I don't see any "sda" directory into it so that this file system file could be mounted on linux partition.

```
mount -o loop rootfs.ext3 /media/fuse/

ls

bin  examples  init   libexec   lost+found  proc  sbin32  tmp
dev  home      lib     mnt      root  share   usr
etc  include   mnth    sbin      var
```

Could any one please point me out how could I provide /dev/sda to this file system file rootfs.ext3 ?

Thanks

Comment: This is confused. Your `rootfs.ext3` is a *file* which contains a *disk image*. You mount it using loop mounting, which create a virtual device.  `/dev/sda` is a *physical disk* (and a whole one, not a partition) --- it's not provided by any image, it's  the kernel itself that create it on boot.

Comment: Rmano , I would like to know what I should provide in my bootargs for  root device if it is mounted on loop device?

Comment: Ah, ok. So your question is "How can I boot linux from a disk image?", correct? It's surely possible with a virtual machine: http://askubuntu.com/questions/64915/how-do-i-install-ubuntu-on-a-virtualbox-client-from-an-iso-image and maybe (but quite complex --- not trivial at all) for a real machine: http://askubuntu.com/questions/121212/using-a-bootable-live-cd-disk-image-mounted-on-the-hard-drive --- you should think about changing the question if this is the case.

Answer (score 1):

With the command

```
mount -o loop rootfs.ext3 /media/fuse/
```

you have already mounted a loop device via the file `rootfs.ext3`, that contains a file system image. The file system is mounted in `/media/fuse`.

Comment: Ok Thanks, Needs to know how it mapped to " root=/dev/sda" whiling passing kernel boot args, is it like "root=/dev/loop" now?