# How do I install OS into VirtualBox?

Tags: software-installation, virtualbox, 18.04

I would like to install Centos to the VirtualBox on Ubuntu 18.04. Does the ISO Image have to be installed to a DVD or USB stick first?

Comment: You just `sudo apt install virtualbox` (https://packages.ubuntu.com/bionic/virtualbox) to install VirtualBox in Ubuntu 18.04.  It's found in multiverse, so you need to enable that repository (if not already done so).  If you are using a 'live' environment (in memory only), you'll eventually run out of memory so can't install everything; it's intended for testing & fixing issues, not using it as if an installed-system.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How do I install Ubuntu on a VirtualBox client from an ISO image?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/64915/how-do-i-install-ubuntu-on-a-virtualbox-client-from-an-iso-image)

Answer (score 1):

You don't need to burn the ISO image to a DVD or create a Boot USB with it. When Virtualbox prompts you for the DVD to install change it to the directory where you've downloaded the Centos ISO:

[image: Install Windows 10]

I couldn't find an image for selecting a Centos ISO but here is an image for installing Windows 10 ISO. Complete instructions found here: https://www.makeuseof.com/tag/how-to-use-virtualbox/